# Magento 2.1 : Add to cart adds 2 products from PDP

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, products, ajaxaddtocart

In magento2.1 add to cart button adds two quantity in cart when you press it for second time.
I mean, on product page when add a product to cart it's ok and adds 1 qty. But on second time when I press **ADD TO CART**, it adds 2 qty and cart qty goes to 3 instead of 2.
Also I didn't use amazon payment. 
what should I do?

Comment: Is this fresh magento 2 setup?

Comment: if you add it a third time what's the qty in cart? 4,5 or 6?

Comment: It adds 5 on third time

Comment: have a child theme from luma

Comment: check in view source if catalogAddToCart is not called twice. In my case it happened  when I had related product listed down on PDP.

Comment: checked it. have not twice add to cart action